# Remove encryption from all s3 objects using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I am looking at [s3api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/index.html) and trying to remove encryption on all my S3 objects. Looks like there is no easy way to remove from CLI. From the console I can do select few (multiple) files but it is tedious.

Suggestions please.. thank you.

Comment: Do you want specific files in bucket or all files across bucket?. If its 2nd one, have you tried?. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-bucket-encryption.html

Comment: I'm almost afraid to ask, but which type of encryption are you trying to remove, and what (other, unstated) problem do you believe this will solve for you?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to remove default S3 encryption on your bucket.

Then, you can use this AWS CLI command that will copy all objects and remove encryption:

`aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/ s3://BUCKET_NAME/ --recursive`

Comment: This work around worked. There is no command to remove encryption on an object